# Let $f(n)$ be the number of prime factors of the positive integer $n$. Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(n)} n$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, limits, prime-factorization

> Let $f(n)$ be the number of prime factors of the positive integer $n$. Find $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(n)} n$.

I suspect it's equal to $0$, but how can I show this? Thank you.

Comment: Note that $2^{f(n)} \leq n$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $2^{f(n)}\le n$, so $f(n)\le \log_2(n)$. Now the standard tools, such as L'Hospital's Rule, can be used to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log_2(x)}{x}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The integer $n$ can have at most one prime factor exceeding $\sqrt n$; therefore $f(n) \le \sqrt n + 1$, which quickly implies that the limit equals $0$.

Answer (score -1):

Since we know infinite that there are infinitely many [primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number), we can take $n$ tending to be an infinitely large prime.

$\dfrac{f(n)}{n}=\dfrac{1}{p}$, here $f(p)=1$(Why?)

---

Comment: This restriction to a subsequence doesn't answer the main question.

Comment: @GregMartin: I disagree. The question is: find the $\lim\frac{f(n)}{n}$. The restriction to the subsequence of prime numbers is a clever way to find that limit. If this problem was a GRE problem this approach would be the best possible. (+1) Inceptio.

Comment: @P..: If the limit exists, there has to be only one limit. The idea of using infinitely many primes surely helps over here. :)

Comment: If you just want to convince yourself of what the limit is, then sure. But presumably, a problem which states "find this limit" should also include a *proof* that the limit exists, rather than *assuming* that the limit exists.

Comment: I'm not considering to delete this answer.(Cause: Its not an *answer*, it was just an *approach*)